# Bigquery API fails to recognize wildcard tables

Tags: google-bigquery

```
SELECT
  timestamp,
  user,
  object_id
FROM
  `x.com:projectx.audit_log.audit_log*`
WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX >= "20190401"
  and event = "EDITED"
```

But when I drag the query into my google apps script project i have problems, it won't recognize the table at all

> JsonResponseException: API call to bigquery.jobs.query failed with error: Invalid table name `x.com:projectx.audit_log.audit_log*`

Is there another way to call wildcard tables?

Edit: the part that seems to be causing problems is enclosing the table in

> `

This works: (for a single table)

```
[x.com:x.audit_log.audit_log_20190801]
```

but this does not

```
`x.com:x.audit_log.audit_log_20190801`
```

Edit2:

This is the error I get for using

```
[x.com:x.audit_log_.audit_log_*]
```

> (table) is not queryable with legacy SQL.

Comment: have you tried just `\`projectx.audit_log.audit_log*\`` or add `#standardSQL` as a first line?

Comment: is "#standardSQL \n Select" what you mean?

Comment: yes on separate line - first line

Comment: if you say that as an answer I can mark it as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add #standardSQL as in below example

```
#standardSQL   
SELECT
  timestamp,
  user,
  object_id
FROM
  `x.com:projectx.audit_log.audit_log*`
WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX >= "20190401"
  and event = "EDITED"
```

on a side note: try also just `projectx.audit_log.audit_log*` - w/o `x.com:` part. Domain part in fully qualified path (`domain:project.dataset.table`) might be optimal in some cases